# How do I write to file in blocks in order to circumvent an error with large file sizes?

Tags: python, file, size, filesize

I have this very simple piece of code:

```
f = open('file.txt','w+')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

The issue is that the string 'result' can be up to several gigabytes in size. Although it is successfully created, writing it to a file results in this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I've read that this is a known issue with running Python in OS X (I'm running 10.13 High Sierra). How can I break the write function up into blocks to get around it?

(I also know this is an insurmountable problem in 32-bit versions due to inherent limitations, but I'm running 64-bit)

Comment: Which filesystem are you writing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing in chunks

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


with open('file.txt','w+') as f:  
    for chunk in chunks(results, 1024):  # try to play with this number
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: This works! However, heads up, you missed a colon at the end of the second-to-last line. Note to anyone else viewing this thread: this slows down write times for smaller strings. However, it may be the *only* way of successfully writing with larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really about lack of memory, you can try appending line by line.

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    for item in result:
        f.write(item)
```

In this case, `result` is a list of lines. You should adapt this based on the content of your `result` object.